# Struts2 <s:select list=mylist"/> via request object rather than in Action class

Tags: struts2

I have a `<s:select list="myList" />` being populated from an `List<String>` that is found in the Action class alongside its associated getters & setters...

As per this simple example

https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/

However I want to know if it's possible not to create a List within the action class but to store a List object on the request

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("value1"); myList.add("value2"); etc...
request.setAttribute("myList", myList);
```

and use that to populate `<s:select list="myList" />`

I have attempted this but I can't get it to work. I want to know if it was something I was doing wrong or it just can't be done ?

My belief was that all data within the form was added to the request anyhow on load of the JSP so shouldn't matter if it was manually added as per above...

Comment: You can, but probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes is possible like below

```java
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("value1"); myList.add("value2"); //etc...
ActionContext actionContext = ActionContext.getContext();
if(null != actionContext) {
        ValueStack stack = actionContext.getValueStack();
        stack.setValue("#request['myList']", myList);
}
```

then

```xml
<s:select list="#request['myList']" />
```

Comment: That is spot on thanks Yasser... Learnt a few new things with tha post !

Comment: No. Why? Don't. The `request.setAttribute` works just fine.

Comment: When I tested this Aleksandr a simple `request.setAttribute` did not work. Setting the list as an object within Action with getters ans setters did and the above suggestion from Yasser also worked...

Comment: @DangerousHamster `setAttribute` and `#request['myList']` in JSP?

Comment: @AleksandrM is right ... `request.setAttribute` and then `#request['myList']` should also work.